# How do I convert .pem file to .ppk file on mac?

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services

I want to convert `.pem file` to `.ppk file` on my `Mac OS`.

The requirement comes because my clients use windows and so I had to provide them `ppk file`, while I use Mac.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the best way you can achieve this is by just convert your existing key with puttygen: `puttygen mykey.pem -o mykey.ppk`

This [resource](http://www.codeblocq.com/2016/05/Convert-a-putty-ppk-key-to-a-pem-file-on-OSX/) explains exactly what you need.

Comment: is it required to install putty for that?

Comment: Well.. with puttygen you can generate ssh keys. So it's a neat tool for this kind of job. Take a look at puttygen, if you have no restrictions on your working space.

Comment: While I assumed Mac's *nix based system would have the right SSH tools built in, most google answers DO seem to still use putty-gen for this task. How interesting!